# Grouping dimensions in Tableau but keep ungrouped data

Tags: grouping, tableau-api

I am plotting sales vs departments over time in tableau. Time is on the column shelf, departments are on the rows shelf while sales is on text marks.

My departments measure is made up of depts. A-E and I would like to roll up depts. A as well as B into "A&B" and leave the rest as is.

On my bar chart I wish to plot time on the x axis, departments on the y-axis and the length of the bars are determined by value.

On my y axis I should see depts A - E as well as a bar for "A&B", in all there should be 6 bars in the bar chart.

I am aware of how to group data in Tableau but when I try it, it just rolls up the group I created and doesn't allow you to retain the original individual entries for comparison.

I'm pretty sure there's an easy way to do this in Tableau but true to form it does the hard things easily and.....

[image]

Comment: Shooting in the dark without a screenshot but try keeping the new group dimension on rows and then dragging the original depts dimension onto the Details mark card (or Labels mark card if you want it as a label).

Comment: can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @SamM thanks for the response but that doesn't get me to where I want. I was hoping to group A & B together but also retain A and B individually, I would therefore have 6 rows, A -> E and another row for A&B grouped. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @TheGoat From a usability and design perspective, what you are describing doesn't make much sense. If your users wants to see grand totals, you will end up having incorrect values. I'd suggest instead that you create a hierarchy with your new grouped dimension and the original dimension. This will allow your user to drill-down or drill-up, seeing detail or summary.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dashboard with 2 sheets. First one will have the A & B group and second one will have all have the rows from A to B.
This may not be an elegant solution but may meet your requirement.